# jquery script inside asp.net update panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have written a jquery script to hide the table border in the document.ready.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".todotable").last().css("border-bottom", "none");
  });
```

Further, I have put the markup inside an asp.net update panel so that it want post back whole page when I need to update the table. Copied the same jquery code and placed it inside the update panel. But its not applying the style changes each time the update panel is loading.

Could not find what the problem is. Do I need to replace the document.ready inside the update panel with something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are loading the content after each request, the document ready handler is not called again.

Instead you need to add the code to the `endRequest` event of the updatePanel. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    // your jQuery code to execute on page load...
});

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function() {
    // code to execute on updatePanel change
    $(".todotable").last().css("border-bottom", "none");
});
```

Comment: You are an absolute genius... Thanks.